# EOFException - readObject called once

Tags: java, deserialization

I know there is many questions regarding this problem, but none of those handles the situation in which `readObject()` is called just once.
Here is the code:

```
try (ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(Paths.get("alert", crashFilePath.toString()).toString()))) {

            Warning crash = (Warning) input.readObject();

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // modify GUI
                }
            });
```

Most of the time this code successfully reads `Warning` object, but sometimes it throws `EOFException`.

Serialization is done like this:

```
Warning warning = new Warning("Crash detected.", timeStamp, a.getX(), a.getY(), a.getFlightHeight());
    Path path = Paths.get("alert", timeStamp);
    try (ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(new File(path.toString() + ".ser")))) {
        output.writeObject(warning);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible your program is exiting before `output.writeObject(warning)` has finished executing?

Comment: @VGR no, the file that has to be deserialized exists.

Comment: That only proves that `new FileOutputStream` executed.  It does not guarantee that `writeObject` finished before the JVM exited.

Comment: If it was really thrown by `readObject()`, the object output stream was created but no object was written. If, as is more likely, it was really thrown by `new ObjectInputStream(...)`, the file exists but is zero length. Both failure conditions are possible, and others, and your code just has to cope with them properly.